# monacaでのlocalStorageの使用について

Tags: javascript, ios, monaca, jquery

monaca にて localStorage を使った Todo アプリを制作しています。
ページ遷移や更新をした際、自動的に localStorage に

Key: `MobileServices.Installation.config`
Value: `{"applicationInstallationId":""}`(""内は英数字の羅列)

といったデータが保存されてしまい、困っています。

一つ一つの Todo データのキーは、0,1,2,3... と Todo が保存されるたびに1足された数字がキーになるようにしています。
それらのキーを for 文で回してデータを取得しているのですが、この自動的に保存されてしまったデータが邪魔をしているのか、思うように取得ができません。

実機デバッグを行った際にこのデータは保存されているようで、プレビューで実行した際にはプログラムもうまく動きます。
実機デバッグを行っているのは iOS 9.2.1 です。

このデータを自動的に保存させないようにする方法がありましたらお教えください。

Comment: 「思うように取得ができません」とのことですが、具体的にどのようなエラーが出ているかわかりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
エラーメッセージは特に出ていません。プレビューでは正常に動くのですが、実機デバッグで動かすと問題のMobileServices.Installation.configというキーが保存され、本来取得したいキーが取得できないという状態です。